# No response from IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, wireshark, netstat, not-responding

My problem is that the Default Web Site can be opened from the server machine (localhost), but cannot be opened from a test machine (which is in the same LAN). Netstat says that IIS 7.5 is listening on 0.0.0.0:80. WireShark shows that the browser on the test machine emits three TCP SYN packets, and these packets reach the web server, but there is no SYN-ACK (etc).

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about connection from localhost, but on external lan card IP? Is not problem with firewall on IIS machine?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to allow "World Wide Web Services (HTTP)" in the firewall settings of the web server.